# Debugging a C# executable that crashes on launch

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I'm trying to remotely debug a C# program.  Connecting to the host is not problem and I can see all the processes on running on that machine, and can connect to the *msvsmon.exe*.

However, the program I want to debug crashes immediately on launch giving me no time to attach myself to it.  Also launching the debug executable in question through a remote location does nothing. How can I attach a debugger before the crash?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Crashing at launch might be due to a missing dependency. Run `fuslogvw.exe` before starting your application and see whether any of the binding operations fail.

If that doesn't help, it is generally a good practice to have diagnostic logging in place. You can use a dedicated logging library, e.g. log4net, or at least you should be using the simplest form of logging via `System.Diagnostics.Trace`. You can listen to the trace messages by either configuring a trace listener in the app.config or using third-party tools like a debugger or **DebugView** from Sysinternals.

If you actually want to attach a debugger you can insert a breakpoint programmatically:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

I haven't checked how this works with a remote debugger, but as a last resort you can have your application sleep long enough to allow you to attach a debugger:

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
```

Answer (score 15):

One of my favorite tricks for attaching a debugger at program launch is using `Image File Execution Options`. It's a registry facility which allows you, amongst other things, attach a debugger to an application before its execution. Same trick allows, for example, replacing your Windows Task Manager with [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer), or `Notepad.exe` with [Notepad2](https://www.flos-freeware.ch/notepad2.html).

You can read all about it [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160220151327/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/greggm/archive/2005/02/21/377663.aspx).

Here's how you set it up:

- Run `regedit.exe`
- Go to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options`
- Create a new key named as your exe (example: yourprogram.exe)
- Create a new string value under your exe. The name of the string value is `Debugger`, and the value is `vsjitdebugger.exe`

When you run the executable, you will see the Just In Time prompt asking you to select a debugger:

[image: vsjitdebugger]

While this dialog is open, attach remotely to your process, and press `No` on the dialog.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Crickey, this is pretty helpful.  Didn't realise this could be done.

Comment: GFlags is a free tool from Microsoft that will set this option in the registry for you, as well as many other useful debugging options. It is available for free at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009.aspx It is well worth using when you need to set a debugger to run every time a program or service runs on a system.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually after much digging around I realised WPF was the cause of the problem.  Rudsen's blog reveals the [answer.](http://www.rudischhauser.de/Blog/post/2010/05/26/The-invocation-of-the-constructor-on-type-UniClientWPFWindow1-that-matches-the-specified-binding-constraints-threw-an-exception.aspx)

In the application log would be the following error;

.NET Runtime 4.0 Error Reporting

EventType clr20r3, P1 eobfrontend.exe, P2 1.0.0.0, P3 4cd95cc7, P4 presentationframework, P5 4.0.0.0, P6 4ba1f8db, P7 78ff, P8 0, P9 system.windows.markup.xamlparse, P10 NIL.

Realised as Rudsen remarked *"that the error means there was a runtime error parsing the xaml code".*  I follow the steps outlined "Open Debug > Exceptions and activate the checkbox in the "thrown" column for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". Done so, Visual Studio will halt on all exceptions."