# Attaching the remote debugger to process that crashes almost immediately

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, remote-debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Debugging a C# executable that crashes on launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4133164/debugging-a-c-executable-that-crashes-on-launch)

Does anyone have a good trick other than

Thread.Sleep(10000);

to attach the remote debugger to process that crashes almost immediately?

Can you start the process with WinDbg and hand it off somehow? I tried this but the process was grayed out and I couldn't hand it off to a different debugger. (My VS2008 in this case)

Comment: What type of app/library are you trying to connect to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this MSDN page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678494.aspx

More specifically, section *Launching a remote process*