# How can Visual C++ launch an application for debugging on a remote PC?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, remote-debugging

This is probably a duplicate but I didn't see it... is it possible to get VC++ to launch an application for debugging on a remote machine, rather than simply attaching to an already running remote executable? Ideally I would like to build, copy the new .exe to the remote machine, and launch it through the debugger, all in some easy fashion.

Is there a nice way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For Visual Studio *2010* see the section "Launching a remote process" at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678494.aspx#scenarios (credit to https://stackoverflow.com/a/6499006/15926)